# Create, save, and load spatial index using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to create a spatial index using GeoPandas once and save it to a file instead of recreating it every time. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you should add a bit more context into the question that demonstrates the problem. Sure, your answer looks good right now but this does not fit the standard of a good question. This would also further highlight the actual needed change which is only 5 lines.

Comment: I disagree. The question is straightforward and does not need more context to be understood by someone trying to solve this problem. What context do *you* mean? Should I contrive a broken code sample and pretend to ask why it doesn't work (even though I'm taking the time to provide an answer)? Explain to the reader what a GeoPandas spatial index is? Quote the API documentation which itself doesn't explain much of anything? How does that create value for the reader? What are these standards you're referring to?

Comment: As I said: the actual answer is 5 lines of code - everything else belongs in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `pickle` library to write a GeoDataFrame to disk. It will give identical results to using `Pandas` method `.to_pickle()`.

```
# Save GeoDataFrame with pickle
with open('gdf_polygons.pkl', 'wb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(gdf_polygons, pickle_file)

# Load GeoDataFrame with pickle
with open('gdf_polygons.pkl', 'rb') as pickle_file:
    gdf_polygons = pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

It is worth noting that for a points-in-polygons analysis, it is faster to use a spatial join, rather than using iteration to find a match. You can use GeoPandas' `.sjoin()` method. As a bonus, when you do a spatial join, GeoPandas will automatically create a spatial index if there is not one already. I reworked Tyler's example to show that this method is faster:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import os
import pandas as pd
import time

shapefile_path = "C:/Data/GIS/US/ZipCodes/tl_2022_us_zcta520.shp"
gdf_zip_codes_file = "gdf_zip_codes.pkl"

# Load the dataframe if it's already been created.
if os.path.exists(gdf_zip_codes_file):
    gdf_zip_codes = pd.read_pickle(gdf_zip_codes_file)
else:
    # Create and save the dataframe and spatial index.
    gdf_zip_codes = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
    gdf_zip_codes.sindex
    gdf_zip_codes.to_pickle(gdf_zip_codes_file)

# Function to find the zip code at a given latitude and longitude.
def find_zip_code(latitude, longitude):
    point = Point(longitude, latitude)
    possible_matches = list(gdf_zip_codes.sindex.intersection((point.x, point.y)))
    for idx in possible_matches:
        if gdf_zip_codes.geometry.iloc[idx].contains(point):
            return gdf_zip_codes['ZCTA5CE20'].iloc[idx]
    return None

def find_zip_code_sjoin(test_coordinates: list) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    # Create a list of Point geometries
    geometry = [Point(lon, lat) for lat, lon in test_coordinates]

    # Create a GeoDataFrame - assume points are in NAD83, epsg 4269
    gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geometry, columns=['lat', 'lng'], crs=gdf_zip_codes.crs)

    # Add the 'lat' and 'lng' values to the DataFrame
    gdf_points['lat'] = [lat for lat, lon in test_coordinates]
    gdf_points['lng'] = [lon for lat, lon in test_coordinates]

    # Perform the spatial join - finds the intersecting polygon for each point
    gdf_joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf_points, gdf_zip_codes, how='left', predicate='intersects', lsuffix='point',
                           rsuffix='poly')

    for index, row in gdf_joined.iterrows():
        print(f"The zip code for latitude {row['lat']}, longitude {row['lng']} is {row['ZCTA5CE20']}.")

    return gdf_joined

# Example coordinates (latitude, longitude).
test_coordinates = [
    (40.7128, -74.0060),   # New York City, NY
    (34.0522, -118.2437),  # Los Angeles, CA
    (41.8781, -87.6298),   # Chicago, IL
    (29.7604, -95.3698),   # Houston, TX
    (33.4484, -112.0740),  # Phoenix, AZ
    (39.9526, -75.1652),   # Philadelphia, PA
    (32.7157, -117.1611),  # San Diego, CA
    (29.9511, -90.0715),   # New Orleans, LA
    (37.7749, -122.4194),  # San Francisco, CA
    (38.9072, -77.0369),   # Washington, D.C.
    (33.7490, -84.3880),   # Atlanta, GA
    (35.2271, -80.8431),   # Charlotte, NC
    (42.3601, -71.0589),   # Boston, MA
    (36.7783, -119.4179),  # Fresno, CA
    (30.2672, -97.7431),   # Austin, TX
    (32.7767, -96.7970),   # Dallas, TX
    (25.7617, -80.1918),   # Miami, FL
    (39.7684, -86.1581),   # Indianapolis, IN
    (47.6062, -122.3321),  # Seattle, WA
    (35.7796, -78.6382),   # Raleigh, NC
]

# Test the function for each pair of latitude and longitude.
# Method #1 with iteration
start_time = time.time()
for latitude, longitude in test_coordinates:
    zip_code = find_zip_code(latitude, longitude)
    if zip_code:
        print(f"The zip code for latitude {latitude}, longitude {longitude} is {zip_code}.")
    else:
        print(f"No zip code found for latitude {latitude}, longitude {longitude}.")

end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time
print(f'Time for method with iteration: {total_time:.6f} seconds')

# Method #2 with spatial joins.
start_time = time.time()
find_zip_code_sjoin(test_coordinates)
end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time
print(f'Time with spatial join: {total_time:.6f} seconds')
```

Results:

```
Time for method with iteration: 0.189 seconds
...
Time with spatial join: 0.036 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid recreating the spatial index each time by [pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) the GeoPandas dataframe.

Using [2022 US Census Zip Code Tabulation Areas](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2022/ZCTA520/tl_2022_us_zcta520.zip) as an example:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

shapefile_path = "tl_2022_us_zcta520.shp"
gdf_zip_codes_file = "gdf_zip_codes.pkl"

# Load the dataframe if it's already been created.
if os.path.exists(gdf_zip_codes_file):
    gdf_zip_codes = pd.read_pickle(gdf_zip_codes_file)
# Create and save the dataframe and spatial index.
else:
    gdf_zip_codes = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
    gdf_zip_codes.sindex
    gdf_zip_codes.to_pickle(gdf_zip_codes_file)

# Function to find the zip code at a given latitude and longitude.
def find_zip_code(latitude, longitude):
    point = Point(longitude, latitude)
    possible_matches = list(gdf_zip_codes.sindex.intersection((point.x, point.y)))
    for idx in possible_matches:
        if gdf_zip_codes.geometry.iloc[idx].contains(point):
            return gdf_zip_codes['ZCTA5CE20'].iloc[idx]
    return None

# Example coordinates (latitude, longitude).
test_coordinates = [
    (40.7128, -74.0060),   # New York City, NY
    (34.0522, -118.2437),  # Los Angeles, CA
    (41.8781, -87.6298),   # Chicago, IL
    (29.7604, -95.3698),   # Houston, TX
    (33.4484, -112.0740),  # Phoenix, AZ
    (39.9526, -75.1652),   # Philadelphia, PA
    (32.7157, -117.1611),  # San Diego, CA
    (29.9511, -90.0715),   # New Orleans, LA
    (37.7749, -122.4194),  # San Francisco, CA
    (38.9072, -77.0369),   # Washington, D.C.
    (33.7490, -84.3880),   # Atlanta, GA
    (35.2271, -80.8431),   # Charlotte, NC
    (42.3601, -71.0589),   # Boston, MA
    (36.7783, -119.4179),  # Fresno, CA
    (30.2672, -97.7431),   # Austin, TX
    (32.7767, -96.7970),   # Dallas, TX
    (25.7617, -80.1918),   # Miami, FL
    (39.7684, -86.1581),   # Indianapolis, IN
    (47.6062, -122.3321),  # Seattle, WA
    (35.7796, -78.6382),   # Raleigh, NC
]

# Test the function for each pair of latitude and longitude.
for latitude, longitude in test_coordinates:
    zip_code = find_zip_code(latitude, longitude)
    if zip_code:
        print(f"The zip code for latitude {latitude}, longitude {longitude} is {zip_code}.")
    else:
        print(f"No zip code found for latitude {latitude}, longitude {longitude}.")

end_time = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
total_time = (datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time,'%H:%M:%S') - datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time,'%H:%M:%S'))

print('Total time: ' + str(total_time))
```

First run:

```bash
The zip code for latitude 40.7128, longitude -74.006 is 10007.
The zip code for latitude 34.0522, longitude -118.2437 is 90012.
The zip code for latitude 41.8781, longitude -87.6298 is 60604.
...
Total time: 0:01:00
```

Second run:

```bash
...
Total time: 0:00:03
```